# Encoding issues in javascript files using rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline (ruby 1.9.2).

I get the following error when trying to serve a javascript `js.erb` file that has utf-8 encoded strings

```
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

I've set `Encoding.default_external = "UTF-8"` in my environment.rb file. How do i get the asset pipeline to serve with a different encoding?

**EDIT**

The error only shows up when I'm generating the utf-8 character outside of the file (in this case by querying from the DB). The error goes away if I add

```
<% "日" %>
```

to the top of the file. I'm guessing there's some kind of encoding guessing going on here, but how do I avoid it without that hacky solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When loading a file, Ruby tries to "guess" its encoding. If no UTF-8 or any other non-ASCII characters are found, it uses US-ASCII as encoding for the file and throws an error if it suddenly encounters a non-ASCII character, which e.g. is loaded at run-time.

The best solution for this problem is to force Ruby to use a certain encoding by adding 
`# encoding: utf-8` as the first line of a .rb file or `<%# encoding: utf-8 %>` if it's a .erb file.

Comment: I'd tried various versions of that (it's .erb so i tried things like <% # encoding: utf-8 %>), this inspired me to try more, and <%# encoding: utf-8 %> works!. update your answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: You're right. While writing the I forgot that you were dealing with a .erb file in which case <%# encoding: utf-8 %> is correct. I updated my answer to express that.

Comment: for some reason I never got notified of this comment / edit. Thanks!

Comment: I'd really like a system-wide solution so I don't need to paste that text at the top of every ERB (doesn't seem very DRY...)

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do this system wide. However with Ruby 2.0 the default encoding was changed from ASCII to UTF-8. So, with Ruby 2.0 this should be problem of the past. See: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/