# Encoding error in JavaScript asset in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, ruby-1.9

I have a Rails (version 3.2.1) project and I recently switched from Ruby 1.8.7 to Ruby 1.9.3. I added encoding comments in all `.rb` and `.erb` files but I have a problem with plain `.js` JavaScript assets. They contain comments in Polish saved with UTF-8 encoding. In most files it works fine - Ruby detects the encoding correctly - but in one file I have only a single UTF-8 character `ś` in a comment line. And now the Rails server fails with `Encoding::CompatibilityError` when displaying index page (which doesn't even reference the JavaScript file).

I know it's a problem with Ruby's automatic encoding detection as it probably can't detect encoding from single character outside ASCII range, but it's very frustrating since it shouldn't matter anyway - the file is only linked to as an asset.

My question is: how to enforce UTF-8 encoding in all `.js` assets?

Comment: did you set the default encoding in your `application.rb` file like `config.encoding = "utf-8"`?

Comment: @phoet yes, I have the line `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try renaming it to js.erb and placing <%# encoding: utf-8 %> at the top

found a hint here: [Encoding issues in javascript files using rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761540/encoding-issues-in-javascript-files-using-rails-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix the problem :)