# encoding problems on rails javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

I've a rails application, with some javascripts (written in UTF-8).
One of the javascripts contains non ANSI characters like à. When the javascript is compiled (one javascript is created from many of them), this characters are wrongly written.

For example, ó becomes Ã³

I know that there must be a problem of encodings, but I don't know how to resolve it. Is somehow to tell rails that my javascripts are UFT-8?
I've tried to add <%# encoding: utf-8 %> to the js file, but its not working.

THanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll borrow @Kodak answer (and emphatize it just a little bit):

> **try renaming it to js.erb** and placing <%# encoding: utf-8 %> at the
>   top

This thread can be found here, with some more information. Hope it helps!

[Encoding error in JavaScript asset in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822597/encoding-error-in-javascript-asset-in-rails)

Comment: As posted in my question  I've tried to add <%# encoding: utf-8 %> to the js file, but its not working.

Comment: But does the file have a .erb extension?