# How to use t() in an erb-compiled javascript-asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a file `app/assets/javascripts/calendar/weekplans.js.erb`, which contains some basic erb:

```
var init_weekplans = function() {
  //..
  allDayText: '<%= t('weekplan.all-day') %>'
  //..
}
```

Rails fails on (pre)compiling this asset with `undefined method 't'`. I'd like to use the `t()` method from ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper in there. How do I include this? Is it wise to include this at all, or should I simply push any such variable from the controller or view into this `init_weekplans` function, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
I18n.t instead of t.
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the trick. I did, however, find a crucial mistake in my thinking: when the asset is precompiled it is no longer multilingual, but compiled with the default language instead; so I need to abandon this idea entirely, unfortunately.

Comment: Yup, you're right. You can take a look at this question though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701749/rails-internationalization-of-javascript-strings