# I18n bootstrap-tour Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, bootstrap-tour

I can't translate my title and my content this is my code for (locales/fr.yml) :

```
fr:
 select: Sélectionnez votre contenu
 content: Choisissez des photos au format paysage pour un meilleur.
```

and for my js:

```
var tour = new Tour({
  smartPlacement: false, // does NOT work every time
  backdrop: true,
  steps: [{
      element: ".tuto1",
      placement: 'bottom',
      title: "<%= I18n.t('select') %>",
      content: "<%= I18n.t('content') %>" 
  }]
});


function startTour() {
  // Initialize the tour
  tour.init();
  // Restart from begining
  tour.restart();
  // Start the tour
  tour.start(true);
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10610347/1086682

Comment: there is not the other way for bootstrap tour ? i can't find in the Doc